# How to figure out exactly where PHP CURL data and then parse is slowing down

Tags: php, performance, curl

I have a PHP script that grabs an XML RSS feed from Google via CURL and then parses and formats it for display on a web page. For several years the HTML page would load instantly, now for that last month it takes about .5 seconds to display. I'm not sure if the slowdown is from retrieving the content or from parsing the data.

The actual RSS web page loads in my web browser instantly
https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en

I'm not sure how to go about debugging the slowdown

Comment: print out the time before and after each operation, and measure - `print microtome(true);` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime

Comment: Thanks, that helped me at least find the part that is slowing everything down. The slowness is CURL. Now I have to figure out why that suddenly sowed down!